Find the galois group of the polynomial $x^3-5$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$
I have taken this problem from J S Milne Field and Galois theory Version $4$ and Page No. $89$, Problem No. A$-43$
Find the galois  group  of the polynomial $x^3-5$  over the  field  $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$
My attempt:The roots of $f(x)=x^3 -5$ are $\sqrt[3]{5}$, $\omega\sqrt[3]{5}$, and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{5}$ where $\omega$ is a third root of unity.
$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]=3$
Here $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})]=2$
$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]=3/2$
I think Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$

I’m so baffled by your posts. Are you joking when you write your attempt? How can the degree of a field extension be 3/2, a fraction?

@CraniumClamp $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[m]{a}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]b)]=m/n$ where $m>n$

@CraniumClamp I might be wrong, but this is what I think.

@jasmine No offense, but this really is a strange mistake. I see you also asked questions about field theory a few years ago, so you surely know that the extension degree has to be a natural number. As for $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]$, such an expression simply doesn't exist, because this is not a field extension. $\sqrt{2}$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$. Maybe this is what confused you.

You're right, I thought $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$ was the field extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$@Mark

The fact that you get a fraction for a degree is a red herring. There must be some mistake and the mistake is

$$\left[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)\right]=\left[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})\right]\left[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)\right]$$

You clearly wanted to use the tower rule. However, the tower rule says

If $F\subseteq L\subseteq K$ are fields, then $[K:F]=[K:L][L:F]$.

The condition of the inclusion are necessary. For your case, that is not true since $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\not\subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5)$.

For a correct approach, let us try to make an actual tower. Consider
$$\Bbb Q\subseteq\Bbb Q(\omega)\subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5,\omega)$$
or
$$\Bbb Q\subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5)\subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5,\omega)$$
Try working your way through either of these.
Hope this helps. :)
